# Decide the Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: R2 → R2 Be the linear image that depicts a point in the plane R2 on the mirror image in line x + y = 0.

(a) Determine the matrix of the standard bases for R2.

I have tried with input of the standard Matrix I to get the standard basis.
But i get wrong answer i get the standard Matrix but it becomes a
2 x 2 matrix with vectors [0 -1] and next row [-1 0].

This below is my answer:

[image]

Picture below is the corrected answer:

[image]

Comment: Why do you claim that that answer is wrong?

Comment: I get [[1 0] [1 0] like the standard matrix when i am using x + y?

Comment: The line $x+y=0$ goes through the origin, with "direction" $(-1,1)$, if you mirror unit vectors along this line, then $(1,0)$ will go to $(0, -1)$ and $(0, 1)$ will go to $(-1,0)$, which are exactly columns of the matrix of $T$.

Comment: @PeterFranek What do you want to show with the Standardbasis?

Comment: The question is written incorrect. It should be `(a) Determine the matrix of T with respect to the standard basis.` Such matrix has, in columns, vectors $T(e_1), T(e_2)$

Comment: @PeterFranek ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $T(1,0)=(0,-1)$ (the reflection of $(1,0)$ on the line $x+y=0$) and that $T(0,1)=(-1,0)$ (the reflection of $(0,1)$ on the sme line). Therefore, the matrix that you're after is indeed $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

---

Here is another possibility. You know that $T(1,-1)=(1,-1)$ and that $T(1,1)=(-1,-1)$. In other words, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{(1,-1),(1,1)\}$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. But then the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}&=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&-\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: Is there some Transformation Matrix i should multiply with Thanks for the answer though?

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of your question.

Comment: Multiply (-1,1) with some Transformation Matrix? @Jose Carlos Santos?

Comment: I see. I will post another answer.

Comment: It is done now.

Comment: Thanks @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One question how do you get the Matrix with Respect to the basis [1 0 0 -1] ? @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128219/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-jonte-yh).